# Upload/Update XSP application to Bluemix through Cloud Foundry API

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm using Cloud Foundry API to modify apps on IBM Bluemix.
I got oauth key and succeeded in calling simple REST requests, like v2/apps.
However, as I want to update XSP application I need to send a nsf file to bluemix.

I tried to use /v2/apps/:guid request, but according to documentation I can only send application parameters, but I cannot send whole application file.

Is there an endpoint to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also an API to [Upload the bits for an App](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/238/apps/uploads_the_bits_for_an_app.html), but if my understanding is correct what you are asking is basically to emulate a *cf push* via REST API. Please note that *cf push* is complex and is not something that is recommended recreating via API on Cloud Foundry. I don't know what your requirements are, but I'd suggest you to use *cf push* to do that. Anyway if you want more information on what are the steps it performs (from an high level perspective) you can take a look [here](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/892938/stories/78235856). I suggest you also to see [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/525) Github Cloud Foundry issue where the user is trying to programmatically recreate the *cf push*.

Comment: I see! That must be it. Thanks for answer!